# Qt C++ xor for a checksum?

Tags: c++, qt, checksum, logical-operators, xor

I am trying to find a way of going through a char array with n amount of hexadecimal values i.e ***{0xA2, 0xE7, 0x5f, 0x1B, 0x11, 0x11, 0x00}*** and I want to try and do a XOR checksum through all of the items in it - to be more precise the **A2 ^ E7 ^ 5F ^ 1B ^ 11 ^ 00** is **10**.

Here is the bit of my code:

```
void MainWindow::checkSum(QByteArray  *b)
{
    qint16 b_len = b->length();

    unsigned char xor = 0;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < b_len ; i ++ )
    {
       xor = xor ^ b[i];
    }
}
```

I think my code should be doing the job however qt does not compile it and gives me the silly error of "2248: 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QByteArray'".

Any ideas on how to make it working?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't pass things by pointer except in circumstances that clearly demand it. By default, you should pass Qt types by const reference when they are in-arguments, and by reference when they are out-arguments. It is conventional to pass `QObject` and derived classes by pointer or pointer-to-const. Small value types, such as types that derive from `QFlags`, should be passed by value.

Comment: You can review your result here: http://www.th-thielemann.de/tools/checksum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `b` as a pointer.

In order to use `operator[]` (and in general, all `operator XX` and assignment operators) you should use an object or a reference to an object, not a pointer.

You should modify your function to:

```
void MainWindow::checkSum(const QByteArray &b)
{
    //Same code as yours
}
```

and your calling should be:

```
{
    QByteArray ba;

    //Fill ba.

    //Now you should not pass a pointer
    //checkSum(&ba) //This should be similar to your call.
    checkSum(ba);   //Now, there is no &.
}
```

Note: if you want to use `opeartor[]` with pointers, you should use a different sintax:

```
void MainWindow::checkSum(QByteArray  *b)
{
   //...
   xor = xor ^ b->operator[](i);
}
```